# EXCEL - Subtract [h]: mm from Decimal

Tags: excel

[image]

The days on the left are formatted in [h]: mm

The **Sum Of Work** is the Sum of the days hours from the left

The **Scheduled Hours** is a number of hours in Decimal Format

I need to get the Scheduled Hours minus the Sum Of Work.

I.e It should be 8.08 to show the amount of hours i have left to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your scheduled hours are in decimal format (`A1`) and sum of work is [h]:mm (`A2`), you can do it like:

```
=A1-A2*24
```

Format it as decimal to get the amount of hours.

Comment: Thats what i wanted but the answer seems to be coming up as 7.80 hours rather than 8.08 hours

Comment: Yes, because this is correct. Provided your scheduled hours are in decimal and sum of work is h:mm. And it seems you're counting as if BOTH of these figures are h:mm.